# select max value for each carID

Tags: sql, oracle

I got three columns (carID, clientID, numClients). First one identifies a client, second one identifies a car and the third one shows how many times each client rented a car.

I need to get the maximum value of numClients for each carID.

I did this:

```
SELECT carID, clientID,
       COUNT(*) AS numClients
    FROM RENT R
    JOIN DETAILS_OF_RENT D ON d.rentID = r.ID
GROUP BY carID, clientID
ORDER BY carID, clientID;
```

So the table I get is something like this:

```
+---------+----------+------------+
|  carID  | clientID | numClients |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 0765BBC | C02      |          1 |
| 0765BBC | C05      |          1 |
| 0765BBC | C07      |          1 |
| 0765BBC | C13      |          1 |
| 0765BBC | C14      |          1 |
| 1234XQP | C01      |          1 |
| 1234XPQ | C02      |          1 |
| 1234XPQ | C07      |          1 |
| 1234XPQ | C09      |          2 |
| 1234XPQ | C11      |          1 |
| 1523BBD | c07      |          1 |
| 1523BBD | c09      |          2 |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

My output should be 0765BBC and 1523BBD since they we're rented by the same client 2 times.

**So, I have to get the carID's of the cars which were rented by the same client more times but I don't know how to select these rows from the above table**

Comment: But in your 0765BBC there are different clients and numClients is 1 for each. Probably means that different clients rented this car all the time. How do you get the car rented by the same client more times if in this case all clients are different and rented this car only once?

Comment: I think I have to get the max times each car was rented by a same client and after that I just need to keep cars with the maximum value.

Comment: You should probably review your test data and add cases where the same car was rented by the same client more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want something like this:

```
SELECT rd.*
FROM (SELECT rd.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY client_cnt DESC) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT carID, clientID, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY clientId) as client_cnt
            FROM RENT R JOIN
                 DETAILS_OF_RENT D
                 ON d.rentID = r.ID
           ) rd
      ) rd
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

I don't think aggregation is needed.  The innermost subquery adds a column which is the total number of cars for each client.  The middle subquery adds a column which identifies the biggest values.  The outer query then chooses the largest values.